# Encrypting a string with Blowfish in ruby returns a shorter string than the same process in php

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, encryption, blowfish

This is confusing me.

When I try and use the following inputs to encrypt a string with Blowfish:
key = "some key"
input = "input string"

I get the following results:

```
ruby: ["79af8c8ee9220bde"]
php: 79af8c8ee9220bdec2d1c9cfca7b13c6
```

I am going to be receiving strings from a php application so I need to get these two to sync up but I don't understand why the php string would be longer. What am I missing?

php code:

```
php > require_once 'Crypt/Blowfish.php';
php > $input = "input string";
php > $key = "some key";
php > $crypt = new Crypt_Blowfish($key);
php > echo bin2hex($crypt->encrypt($input));
79af8c8ee9220bdec2d1c9cfca7b13c6
```

ruby code:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'crypt/blowfish'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> input = "input string"
=> "input string"
irb(main):004:0> key = "some key"
=> "some key"
irb(main):005:0> blowfish = Crypt::Blowfish.new(key)
=> #<Crypt::Blowfish:0xb74b10c4 @sBoxes=[[3156471959, 1769696695, 1443271708, 181204541, 
...... 1894848609], @key="some key">
irb(main):006:0> blowfish.encrypt_block(input)
=> "y\257\214\216\351\"\v\336"
irb(main):007:0> blowfish.encrypt_block(input).unpack("H*")
=> ["79af8c8ee9220bde"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Crypt_Blowfish` either uses [`mcrypt`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php) or acts just like it, you're encountering a padding issue.  In particular, the string is being right-padded with null bytes until it's as long as a multiple of the block size.  From the PHP interactive shell:

```
php > $bf = mcrypt_module_open('blowfish', '', 'ecb', '');
php > $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($bf), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
php > $key = 'some key';
php > mcrypt_generic_init($bf, $key, $iv);
php > echo mcrypt_enc_get_block_size($td);
8
php > echo bin2hex(mcrypt_generic($bf, 'input string'));
79af8c8ee9220bdec2d1c9cfca7b13c6
php > echo bin2hex(mcrypt_generic($td, "input string\0\0\0\0"));
79af8c8ee9220bdec2d1c9cfca7b13c6
```

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to change the [padding mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) in `mcrypt`, and I don't know who wrote the library you're using.  Check for a padding mode in the module's documentation.

With any luck, you can just set Ruby's padding mode instead, or simply null-pad the string on Ruby's side.

Answer (score 4):

Hold on, your Ruby output is 8 bytes? Your input is 12 - it's the Ruby code that's in error here.

I haven't used Crypt::Blowfish (and the documentation is scarce) but you may need to pad your input to a multiple of 64 bits, anyway.

Comment: Good eyes.  Only one actual block is being encoded by the example code given in the question.  This is probably the actual source of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since Blowfish is a 64-bit block cipher you'll have to [pad the data](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2007/11/15/blowfish-in-the-url) and the Ruby implementation doesn't do that for you automatically.

```
s = "input string"
len = s.length
mod = 8-len%8
padded = s.ljust(len+mod, "\0")
```

I just have to show my first attempt...

<strike>encrypted = blowfish.encrypt_block(input.
                                       each_char.
                                       each_slice(8).
                                       map {|slice| 
                                             slice.count==8 ? slice.join : slice.join.ljust(8,"\0")}.join</strike>

I used \0 since that it seems that that is what PHP uses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Crypt/Blowfish.php is or what it's ->encrypt() method does but it's likely the difference in string is php using a salt when calling crypt().

Comment: A salt would generate a totally different result, not just extra characters on the end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the php custom Blowfish script is encrypting incorrectly.

In PHP4 and PHP5, you can use the built in `crypt` function to encrypt with Blowfish.

[PHP crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).

> CRYPT_BLOWFISH - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 base 64 digits from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string. The two digit cost parameter is the base-2 logarithm of the iteration count for the underlying Blowfish-based hashing algorithmeter and must be in range 04-31, values outside this range will cause crypt() to fail.

So you can call `$hash = crypt($yourString, '$2a$07$'.$aSalt)` to encrypt using Blowfish.

If you don't have access to the PHP code, ignore this answer entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try `blowfish.encrypt_string` instead of `encrypt_block`