# Decrypting a blowfish encrypted string in ruby only returns 1/2 the string

Tags: ruby, encryption, blowfish

This is related to my question from yesterday (which got great results):
[Encrypting a string with Blowfish in ruby returns a shorter string than the same process in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465148/encrypting-a-string-with-blowfish-in-ruby-returns-a-shorter-string-than-the-same)

Now I have what I believe to be a similar problem in the opposite direction. I use php to encrypt a string:

```
php > require_once 'Crypt/Blowfish.php';
php > $input = "input string";
php > $key = "some key";
php > $crypt = new Crypt_Blowfish($key);
php > echo bin2hex($crypt->encrypt($input));
79af8c8ee9220bdec2d1c9cfca7b13c6
```

And this is exactly the expected result. However, when I attempt to decrypt the string in ruby, it only gives me a subset of the input:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
r=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'crypt/blowfish'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> key = "some key"
=> "some key"
irb(main):004:0> input = "79af8c8ee9220bdec2d1c9cfca7b13c6"
=> "79af8c8ee9220bdec2d1c9cfca7b13c6"
irb(main):005:0> block = input.gsub(/../) { |match| match.hex.chr }
=> "y\257\214\216\351\"\v\336\302\321\311\317\312{\023\306"
irb(main):006:0> blowfish = Crypt::Blowfish.new(key)
=> #<Crypt::Blowfish:0xb73acbd8 @sBoxes=[[3156471959, 1769696695, 1443271708, 181204541, 
... 1894848609], @key="some key">
irb(main):008:0> blowfish.decrypt_block(block)
=> "input st"
```

Any idea what foolish thing I'm doing now?

Comment: Off topic but any reasons you are using Blowfish? New designs really should use AES, more secure (longer block size for a start, and way better studied) and gaining more and more CPU hardware support so bound to be the fastest solution on more computers each days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A blowfish block is [8-bytes long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29). Note that's exactly the number of characters you're getting back when you ask to decrypt one block.

There must be more code to get the final block, or you need to call decrypt_block again on the next 8-bytes.

Instead of calling decrypt_block you might want to try decrypt_string.

From the tests:

```
userkey = "A BIG KEY"
bf = Crypt::Blowfish.new(userkey) 
string = "This is a string which is not a multiple of 8 characters long"
encryptedString = bf.encrypt_string(string)
decryptedString = bf.decrypt_string(encryptedString)
assert_equal(string, decryptedString)
```

Comment: I have a Java blowfish encrypted string but in ruby after calling bf.decrypt_string I get a long string like ""\ve)\xC7\xBD\xB4\....". So it seems there is e difference between Java and Ruby blowfish